# Laser lens and power

Tags: laser

My little $20$ laser pen;  $5\space mW$ red dot laser will reflect off of a road sign from a quarter of a mile in full sun.  I added a $30^0$ fan line lens and the line is almost invisible during the day.

I need to be able to see a portion of a laser line reflection in full sun reflected off of reflection material similar the reflective tape found on trailers,  and road signs from a distance of $300'$.  The quarter mile I get with a dot laser is cool,  but I don't need that.  $300' - 500'$ is sufficient.

I assume that  a $5^0$ angle lens,  or smaller,  has a better chance of working than the $30^0$ that I am trying to use.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Even a lens which spreads out the laser beam to a 'small' full-cone angle of 5˚ will result in the laser illuminating a circle about 26 feet in diameter at a distance of 300 feet. Don't know what the natural divergence of your laser pen is, but I would guess that it's a lot less than 5˚ which would mean that a 5˚ lens will greatly decrease the laser intensity at 300 feet. Might help if you told us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If it is bouncing off reflecting tape you can assume that the light is bouncing back at all angles.

This means that the brightness only depends on how much the light going to the target spreads out. So to a first approximation the brightness is proportional to the angle, so a 5deg line will be 5/30 = 6x brighter than a 30deg line.